# Get multiple missing dates from bigquery sql query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, date-arithmetic

I have a BigQuery table that keeps track of user sign ins:

| user_id | user_name | user_sign_in_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john doe | 2019-04-05 |
| 1 | john doe | 2019-04-06 |
| 2 | bob bobson | 2019-04-05 |
| 2 | bob bobson | 2019-04-08 |
| 3 | jane beer | 2019-04-05 |
| 3 | jane beer | 2019-04-06 |
| 3 | jane beer | 2019-04-07 |
| 3 | jane beer | 2019-04-08 |
| 4 | amy face | 2019-04-09 |

I want to be able to get users who have not signed in on certain dates and list the dates they have missed. For example, if I want to see users who have not signed in between 2019-04-05 and 2019-04-08, I would need a SQL query that could help me generate something like:

```
[
  {
    'user_id': 1,
    'user_name': 'john doe',
    'dates_not_signed_in': ['2019-04-07', '2019-04-08']
  },
  {
    'user_id': 2,
    'user_name': 'bob bobson',
    'dates_not_signed_in': ['2019-04-06', '2019-04-07']
  },
  {
    'user_id': 4,
    'user_name': 'amy face',
    'dates_not_signed_in': ['2019-04-05', '2019-04-06', '2019-04-07', '2019-04-08']
  }
]
```

I think I need to do something like

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table
```

to get all the user IDs but then I'm not sure how to surround that query so that I only get back users who didn't sign in on certain dates *with* the dates they missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider also below approach

```
select * from (
  select user_id, user_name,
    array_to_string(array(
      select cast(day as string) from unnest(generate_date_array('2019-04-05', '2019-04-08')) day
      except distinct select cast(day as string) from unnest(arr) day
    ), ', ') as dates_not_signed_in
  from (
    select user_id, user_name, array_agg(user_sign_in_date) arr
    from your_table
    group by user_id, user_name
  )
)
where dates_not_signed_in != ''
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Worked! Final q:
`SELECT *, ARRAY_LENGTH(dates_missed) as num_dates FROM (SELECT id, name, array(SELECT CAST(day AS date) FROM UNNEST((SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(date_range) AS array_concat_agg FROM(SELECT generate_date_array(start_date, end_date) AS date_range FROM (date_q) AS items))) day
      EXCEPT DISTINCT SELECT CAST(day AS date)
      FROM UNNEST(arr) day
  ) AS dates_missed
  FROM (
      SELECT id, name, array_agg(inspection_start_timestamp) arr
      FROM table,
      GROUP BY id, name))
WHERE dates_missed is not null`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_date_array` to enumerate the dates, and then check whether each user signed in at each date.

In normal usage, you would have a separate table to store the users, like `users(user_id, user_name)`. I would also assume that the sign-in dates have a time portion. So:

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, array_agg(dt order by dt) dates_not_signed_in
from users u
cross join unnest(generate_date_array('2019-04-05', '2019-04-08', interval 1 day)) as dt
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from sign_ins s 
    where s.user_sign_in_date >= dt and s.s.user_sign_in_date < dt + interval 1 day
)
group by u.user_id, u.user_name
```